# SQL selecting records except when the type is certain kind and prior or same date as the id

Tags: sql, teradata

Trying to select all the records except when type is small and prior or same date as the identical id

```
id  date    type
1   02/09/2012  BIG
2   05/16/2012  BIG
2   06/18/2012  BIG
3   08/08/2011  BIG
3   09/13/2011  BIG
4   06/08/2016  BIG
4   05/27/2016  SMALL
5   08/16/2012  BIG
5   08/15/2012  SMALL
6   09/05/2012  BIG
7   09/05/2012  BIG
7   02/13/2013  BIG
7   08/03/2011  BIG
7   05/09/2012  BIG
7   04/24/2013  SMALL
8   03/31/2017  BIG
8   03/06/2017  SMALL
9   02/17/2016  SMALL
```

My code that I attempted

```
select id, date, type
from (select id, date,type,   min(case when type = 'SMALL' then date end) 
over (partition by id) as min_dt
from table1 as t ) t
where date>min_dt
group by 1,2,3
```

This one gave me only these records

```
id  date    type    
4   06/08/2016  BIG
5   08/16/2012  BIG
8   3/31/2017   BIG
```

but these are the once which I am expecting

```
id  date    type    
1   2/9/2012    BIG 
2   5/16/2012   BIG 
2   6/18/2012   BIG 
3   8/8/2011    BIG 
3   9/13/2011   BIG 
4   6/8/2016    BIG 
4   5/27/2016   SMALL   X
5   8/16/2012   BIG 
5   8/15/2012   SMALL   X
6   9/5/2012    BIG 
7   9/5/2012    BIG 
7   2/13/2013   BIG 
7   8/3/2011    BIG 
7   5/9/2012    BIG 
7   4/24/2013   SMALL   
8   3/31/2017   BIG 
8   3/6/2017    SMALL   X
9   2/17/2016   SMALL
```

expecting all except the wrong once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select id, date, type from table1 t
Where type <> ‘SMALL’ or 
not exists(select date from table1 
where id = t.id and date >= t.date and type <> 'SMALL')
```

**Edit:**

Based on the OP's statement, we are getting all records except where

**1.** *type is small*

**2.** *prior or same date as the identical id* 

 (I take this as the date is less than or equal to at least 1 other record with the same id)

are both true,

meaning we will get the records for which at least one of the conditions is false.

Hence `type <> ‘SMALL’`  gets records where first condition is false

```
or not exists(select date from table1 
    where id = t.id and date >= t.date and type <> 'SMALL')
```

gets records where second condition is false eg. where there is no record with the same id to which the data is less than or equal

Comment: You need to modify your EXISTS-condition to `where id = t.id and date >= t.date and type <> 'SMALL')` to catch the *prior or same date* condition.

Comment: Please provide some information as to how the code above answers the question in order to improve this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.type <> 'SMALL' or
      exists (select 1
              from table1 tt1
              where tt1.id = t1.id and tt1.date < t1.date
             );
```

Comment: Doesn't return the last row `9   2/17/2016   SMALL`

Comment: @Gordon yes this query does not give the last row which was expected.

Answer (score 1):

This applies the same logic as @AnthonyMcGrath solution, but using an OLAP-function: check for SMALL rows (using a runnning total) if another row <> SMALL with a later or equal date exists and discard it.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
QUALIFY 
   type <> 'SMALL' -- all other rows
OR -- it's SMALL
   Min(CASE WHEN type <> 'SMALL' THEN date END) -- returns NULL if there's no later row
   Over (PARTITION BY id
         ORDER BY date DESC
           ,CASE WHEN type <> 'SMALL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END -- same date-> ensure SMALL is sorted last
         ROWS Unbounded Preceding) IS NULL
```

Rephrasing your logic to *"return a SMALL row only when it's the latest one"* seems to work with a ROW_NUMBER, too:

```
QUALIFY type_ <> 'SMALL'
  OR Row_Number() -- get the latest row if it's SMALL
     Over (PARTITION BY id
           ORDER BY date DESC
             ,CASE WHEN type <> 'SMALL' THEN 0 ELSE 1 end) = 1
```